# Pip does ONLY install old and wrong version of my own package

Tags: pip

I am working on a package https://pypi.org/project/sgraphic/ it is at version 0.1.1 but pip does not care. It only installs version 0.0.3

I've tried many solutions suggested here without luck. Ugprading pip, installing packages with no_cache but nothing works.

Any ideas what to try?

Here is a dump of me trying to upgrade

```
pip install sgraphic --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: sgraphic in /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.3)
Collecting sgraphic
  Downloading sgraphic-0.1.1.tar.gz (4.4 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: skia-python in /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sgraphic) (87.1)
Requirement already satisfied: IPython in /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sgraphic) (7.22.0)
  Using cached sgraphic-0.1.0.tar.gz (4.4 kB)
  Using cached sgraphic-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: easing-functions in /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sgraphic) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sgraphic) (1.20.3)
  Using cached sgraphic-0.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
```

when running pip show sgraphic i get

```
Name: sgraphic
Version: 0.0.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the current version (0.1.1) requires PIL, which cannot be installed using `pip`:

```
pip install sgraphic==0.1.1
Collecting sgraphic==0.1.1
  Using cached sgraphic-0.1.1.tar.gz (4.4 kB)
Collecting skia-python
  Using cached skia_python-87.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (4.3 MB)
Collecting IPython
  Using cached ipython-7.27.0-py3-none-any.whl (787 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from sgraphic) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL
```

Because `pip` cannot install all dependencies, it fails to install sgraphic 0.1.1. However, if you do not explicitly request this version, `pip` will try to find an older version that it can install. Apparently, version 0.0.3 is the latest version it can install, so in your case it did that.

I think this is simply a bug in the latest versions of the sgraphic package. The code contains `import PIL`, but the package that contains PIL is actually called Pillow. It's also possible that (the original) PIL is supposed to be installed in another way, but I could not find any information about that.

NB: I created an [issue on github](https://github.com/ReneTC/sgraphic/issues/1) to ask the author of the package. It was indeed a bug and is now fixed in version 0.1.2, which I could install successfully using `pip`.